# Breeze manage NODB EntityTypes with DB EntityTypes

Tags: breeze

i´m using the Papa's course CCJS code to investigate Breeze.js and SPA. Using this code i´m trying to manage aditional information that cames from server but that is not an Entity contained in the Metadata that cames from EntityFramework.

So i created a NO-DB class called Esto and a Server method like Lookups:

```
  [HttpGet]
  public object Informacion()
    {
       var a = new Esto(....);
       var b = new Esto(.....);
       var c = new Esto(......);

    return new {a,b,c};
    }
```

then in model.js inside configureMetadataStore i call:

```
metadataStore.addEntityType({
    shortName: "Esto",
    namespace:"CodeCamper",
    dataProperties:{
      id: {dataType: breeze.DataType.Int32,isPartOfKey: true},
      name: {dataType: breeze.DataType.String}
      }
   };
```

and also define in the model entityNames array:  esto:'Esto' as an Entity

now in the context.js i load this creating a server side method like getLookups but called getInformacion:

```
    function getInformacion(){
            return EntityQuery.from('Informacion')
                   .using(manager).execute()
     }
```

and then inside primeData in the success method call this:

```
datacontext.informacion = {
    esto: getLocal('Esto',nombre)};
```

where getLocal is:

```
  function getLocal(resource, ordering)
   {
        var query = EntityQuery.from(resource).orderBy(ordering);
        return manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
   }
```

I get an error in the query contained in the getLocal that states that Can not find EntityType for either entityTypeName: 'undefined' or resourceName:'Esto'.

What i´m doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were almost there! :-) Had you specified the target `EntityType` in the query I think it would have worked.

Try this:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from(resource).orderBy(ordering).toType('Esto');
```

The `toType()` method tells Breeze that the top-level objects returned by this query will be of type `Esto`.

### Why?

Let's think about how Breeze interprets a query specification.

Notice that you began your query, as we usually do, by naming the **resource** which will supply the data. This resource is typically a path segment to a remote service endpoint, perhaps the name of a Web API controller method ... a method named "Foos".

It's critical to understand that **the query resource name is rarely the same as the `EntityType` name!**   They may be similar - "Foos" (plural) is similar to the type name "Foo" (singular). But the resource name could be something else. It could be "GetFoos" or "GreatFoos" or anything at all.  What matters is that the service method returns "Foo" entities.

Breeze needs a way to correlate the **resource** name with the **`EntityType`** name. Breeze doesn't know the correlation on its own. The `toType()` method is one way to tell Breeze about it.

#### Why do remote queries work without `toType()`?

You generally don't add `toType()` to your queries. Why now?

Most of the time [1], Breeze doesn't need to know the `EntityType` ***until after the data arrive*** from the server. When the JSON query results includes the type name (as they do when they come from a Breeze Web API controller for example), Breeze can map the arriving JSON data into entities without our help ... assuming that these type names are in metadata.

#### Local cache queries are different

When you query the cache ... say with `executeQueryLocally` ...  Breeze must know which cached entity-set to search ***before it can query locally***.

It "knows" if you specify the type with `toType()`. But if you omit `toType()`, Breeze has to make do with the query's resource name.

Breeze doesn't guess. Instead, it looks in an EntityType/ResourceName map for the entity-set that matches the query resource name.

The resource name refers to a service endpoint, not a cached entity-set. There is no entity-set named "Informacion", for example. So Breeze uses an **EntityType/ResourceName** map to find the entity type associated with the query resource name.

#### EntityType/ResourceName

The **EntityType/ResourceName** map is one of the items in the Breeze `MetadataStore`. You've probably never heard of it. That's good; you shouldn't have to think about it ... unless you do something unusual like define your own types.

The map of a new `MetadataStore` starts empty. Breeze populates it from server metadata if those metadata contain EntityType/Resource mappings.

For example, the Breeze `EFContextProvider` generates metadata with mappings derived from `DbSet` names. When you define a `Foo` class and exposed it from a `DbContext` as a `DbSet` named "Foos", the `EFContextProvider` metadata generator adds a mapping from the "Foos" resource name to the `Foo` entity type.

Controller developers tend to use `DbSet` names for method names. The conventional Breeze Web API controller "Foo" query method looks like this:

```
[Get]
public IQueryable<Foo> Foos() {...}
```

Now if you take a query such as this:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('Foos').where(...);
```

and apply it to the cache

```
manager.query.executeLocally(query).then(...);
```

it just works.

Why? Because

- "Foos" is the name of a `DbSet` on the server
- The `EFContextProvider` generated metadata mapping ["Foos" to `Model.Foo`]
- The Web API Controller offers a `Foos` action method.
- The BreezeJS `query` specifies "Foos"
- The `executeLocally` method finds the ["Foos"-to-`Model.Foo`] mapping in metadata and applies the query to the entity-set for `Foo`.

The end-to-end conventions work silently in your favor.

... until you mention a resource name that is not in the EntityType/ResourceName map!

#### Register the resource name

*No problem!*

You can add your own resource-to-entity-type mappings as follows:

```
var metadataStore = manager.metadataStore;
var typeName = 'some-type-name';
var entityType = metadataStore.getEntityType(typeName);

metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName(resource, entityType);
```

Breeze is also happy with just the name of the type:

```
metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName(resource, typeName);
```

In your case, somewhere near the top of your `DataContext`, you could write:

```
var metadataStore = manager.metadataStore;
// map two resource names to Esto
metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName('Esto', 'Esto'); 
metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName('Informacion', 'Esto');
```

#### Don't over-use `toType()`

The `toType()` method is a good short-cut solution when you need to map the top-level objects in the query result to an `EntityType`. You don't have to mess around with registering resource names.

However, you must remember to add `toType()` to every query that needs it. Configure Breeze metadata with the resource-to-entity-type mapping and you'll get the desired behavior every time.

#### Notes

[1] "*Most of the time, Breeze doesn't need to know the `EntityType` until after the data arrive from the server.*"  One important exception - out of scope for this discussion - is when the query filter involves a Date/Time.

Comment: Thanks, really this helps me to understand how Breeze really works

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem here is that you are assuming that entity type names and resource names are the same thing.  A resource name is what is used to execute a query

```
var q = EntityQuery.from(resourceName);
```

In your case the "resourceName" is "Informacion" and the entityType is actually "Esto".  Breeze is able to make this connection on a remote query because it can examine the results returned from the server as a result of querying "Informacion" and seeing that they are actually "Esto" instances.  This is not possible for a local query because Breeze doesn't know what local collection to start from.

In this case you need to give Breeze a little more information via the *MetadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName* method.  Something like this:

```
var estoType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Esto");
manager.metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName("Informacion", estoType);
```

Note that this is not actually necessary if the resource was defined via Entity Framework metadata, because Breeze automatically associates all EF EntitySet names to resource names, but this information isn't available for DTO's.

Note also that a single entity type can have as many resourceNames as you like.  Just make sure to register the resourceNames  before you attempt a local query.

Comment: Thanks Jay for your answer. Good Work with Breeze